# win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Application instance at 0x2584370933424

Tags: python, win32com

My code is below. BUt i am getting error

```
xlapp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
xlapp.Interactive = False
xlapp.Application.EnableEvents = False
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False  # Suppress any Alert windows, which require User action
xlapp.AskToUpdateLinks = False  # Disable automatic update linking
xlapp.Visible = False  # Run the Application in the background

pathname = os.path.dirname(destination_file)
path = os.path.abspath(pathname) + '\\'
out_file = path + destination_file

print(f"The outfile path is {out_file}")

# Open the workbook in said instance of Excel
wb_7 = xlapp.workbooks.open(out_file)

# Refresh all data connections.
wb_7.RefreshAll()
xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
wb_7.Save()
wb_7.Close(True)
wb_7 = None  # Unset wb_7 variable (This is to ensure it's closed)

xlapp.Interactive = True
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = True  # Suppress any Alert windows, which require User action
xlapp.AskToUpdateLinks = True  # Disable automatic update linking
xlapp.Application.EnableEvents = True
xlapp.Visible = True  # Run the Application in the background
xlapp.Quit()  # Close Excel
```

i am getting the below error...
couldnt able to get what i need to fix here
i need some suggestion

```
raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Application instance at 
0x2584370933424>' object has no attribute 'workbooks'
```

Answer (score 2):

win32 objects are Case sensitive, so would need to capitalize.

```
wb_7 = xlapp.workbooks.open(out_file)
```

would need to be

```
wb_7 = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(out_file)
```